# "Pending purchase and activation.." how much time will it take to activate iOS developer program?

Tags: ios-appstore

"Pending purchase and activation.."  how much time will it take to activate iOS developer program

i have enrolled on 19 jan 2013.still it is pending.Any suggestions?

Comment: About 12 hours, I applied at a great time, and there's about 12 hour of time difference from where I am living. LOL

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple the activation should be emailed to you in no more than 24 hours after purchase.

"If it has been more than 24 hours and you have not received your email, please contact us."

https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/purchase-and-next-steps.html